# While creating a new Graphical RunBook Can't load the Graphical editor in Azure Automation?

Tags: azure, azure-automation, runbook

I am creating a New Runbook in Azure Automation But it can't showing the **Graphical Editor** & **Activity Library** for to design the RunBook.
[image]

Comment: Looks like either a bug or a corrupted workflow - does it do this when creating a new, blank workflow as well?  If so use the portal to report the error to the product group.

Comment: What browser are you using? There is a known issue similar to this one when Firefox is used. Can you try the same in Internet Explorer, Edge, or Chrome?

Comment: am using 43.0.1 Firefox version.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this is a know issue with Authoring Blade on Firefox browser. We are looking into fixing this. In the meantime, please use Chrome or Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge where this problem is not present.

Comment: One year later: The issue still exists. But thank you for the hint regarding Firefox. It saved my day.